# c++ check for TCP window full?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I am writing a c++ server application running on Linux.
An iOS client app opens a TCP connection to the server, and the server starts sending messages on the connection.
When the iOS app is put in the background, e.g. by the user switching to another app, the app stops reading data from the socket, but the socket is still open in iOS. The server keeps sending until the buffer window is full, and then hangs in the send() call.
Is there a way to detect that the send() call will hang before calling? Or a way to get out of the call, when it hangs, e.g. setting a timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the sending socket in non-blocking mode.

Use `fcntl()` to `F_SETFL` the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on the socket.

Your properly-written code should already be checking the return value from `send()`, since even with blocking sockets `send()` may indicate that fewer bytes were written than were requested.

In non-blocking mode, `send()` will simply return immediately, with a return value of -1 and `errno` equal to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`. Then, use `poll()` or `select()` to check when the socket can be written to next.

Comment: `send()` will return immediately with an *error*, return code of -1, if no bytes were written. The only way it can return zero is if you supplied a zero length.

Answer (score 0):

Put the socket into non-blocking mode and detect `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `select` or `poll` with a zero timeout and your single socket as a write file descriptor/handle.